# How to implement Singleton class in Activity Class

Tags: java, android, singleton

I want to make my a single Training available in whole application. Let's say each single Training from main activity listview. But I am not getting the values from Singleton class. What is the problem in my code. I have been trying since yesterday and couldn't figure out why?? Thanks for your help in advance.

Here is Singleton class:

```
public class CurrentTraining {

private Training training; //Training is my model class.

private static CurrentTraining instance;

private CurrentTraining() {

}

public static CurrentTraining getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new CurrentTraining();
    return instance;

}

public Training getTraining() {
    return training;
}

public Training setTraining(Training training) {
    return this.training = training;
}
```

}

My Main activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

private Portfolio portfolio;

private ListAdapter trainingListAdapter;

private Dialog dialog;

Training currentTraining;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    currentTraining = CurrentTraining.getInstance().getTraining();

    portfolio = new Portfolio(this);

    trainingListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Training>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            portfolio.getTrainingArrayList());

    setListAdapter(trainingListAdapter);

    ((ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list))
            .setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    Log.i ("DEBUG" , currentTraining.getTitle());
    CurrentTraining.getInstance().setTraining(currentTraining);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on position : " + arg2 + " and ID : " + currentTraining.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

OnClick to the listView it crashes because of NullPointer Exception.

Comment: Personnaly is don't use singletons in Android development. You already have one singleton object -> the application object. You can manage all "singleton's" there by a simple getter and setter. In your activity just cal ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getSingletonObject()

Comment: Singleton Activity? Don't do that!

Comment: He is not creating a Singleton Activity! Usualy user1281750 approach would be the most elegenat way. But yould you please show us a LogCat´?

Comment: @user1281750 I do not get you at all. May be you are trying to say application extends Application{}. I do not want to use that.

I just need help hoe can I implement the CurrentTraining class in my Activity class in this case. Thanks..

Comment: please edit your post and insert is in [CODE] brakets (whole stacktrace pls)

Comment: [E/AndroidRuntime(19060): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(19060): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(19060): at.Packagename.MainActivity.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:54)
E/AndroidRuntime(19060):at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
 E/AndroidRuntime(19060):at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
 E/AndroidRuntime(19060):at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
 E/AndroidRuntime(19060): at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Log.i ("DEBUG" , currentTraining.getTitle());
    CurrentTraining.getInstance().setTraining(currentTraining);
```

not ever set value, how to get the value?

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        currentTraining = (Training)arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
        Log.i ("DEBUG" , currentTraining.getTitle());

        CurrentTraining.getInstance().setTraining(currentTraining);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on position : " + arg2 + " and ID : " + currentTraining.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: While making a arraylist of Trainings. I have already made Training traininig = new Training(). So I do not want to make another new again. Instead I want to use same training object instead.

And the code you gave me does not work. :(

Comment: show me the code with new Training(), i did not see where 'new Training()' is

Comment: I have Portfolio class where I have method to get trainings arraylist. There I have made a new Training.
[Training training = new Training();
training.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor
         .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRAINING_ID)));

this.trainingArrayList.add(training);]

And I have getter and setter for the trainingArrayList.

Comment: you did not set currentTraining in method onItemClick, i have changed the answer, u can try it again.

Comment: U r welcome. we can discuss when u r in problem in future. And finish this question

Comment: How can I finish this question? No idea. New in StackOverFlow.

Comment: just click the check on the left

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate you do this:

```
currentTraining = CurrentTraining.getInstance().getTraining();
```

Which, I think, is returning null since you did not set it yet. When you enter onItemClick() you log with

```
currentTraining.getTitle()
```

which might give the NullPointerException. Try logging with

```
Log.i ("DEBUG" , currentTraining);
```

first to make sure that's not null.

Comment: By setting an instance of Training on your singleton CurrentTraining. Maybe provide a default instance until you have selected one from the list

Answer (score 0):

you get an NPE on this line

Log.i ("DEBUG" , currentTraining.getTitle());

because `currentTraining` is null. The singleton static method `getInstace()` initialises the `instance` field but not field returned by `getTraining()`

Comment: you have to call setTraining before calling getTraining.getTitle and checking for null values

Comment: @blackbelt-- Shit it gives null values for the currentTraining. Why is so??

Comment: because when you retrieve in in the onCreate it is not yet initialized

Comment: @blackbelt-- Even I set like this on onCreate();
currentTraining = CurrentTraining.getInstance().setTraining(currentTraining);
  
  Log.i("DEBUG","" + currentTraining);
The value is null. Could you please take a look in my Singleton class (CurrentTraining.java). If I am doing correct way?

Comment: it does not make sense to me